# Can I have a ReactClass inside a ReactClass?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried this but no success.

```
var osDD = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        dat: React.PropTypes.array
    },
    render: function(){
        var li = this.props.dat;
        console.log(li);
        return (
            <ul><li></li></ul>
        )
    }
});

var osPre = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var osdd = React.createElement(
            osDD,
            {dat: this.props.dat}
        );

        return (
            <div>
                <header>{this.props.title}</header>
                <p>{this.props.description}</p>
                <span className="opt_serv_price">{this.props.price}</span>
                <osdd/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

This simply renders an empty tag `<osdd/>` in the DOM.

Perhaps I'm not doing it the React way. I just started playing with React only recently after watching some videos and doing some reading.

Comment: try `<osDD dat={this.props.dat}/>` instead of `<osdd/>`.

Comment: @JDavidSmith thanks, but give the elem a `dat` attribute and still doesn't render correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I came across this site (http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/react.html#nesting) and it talks about nesting in React.

So tried to follow accordingly and updated my codes to be:

```
var osDD = React.createClass(/*no changes*/);
var osPre = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    return (
        <div>
            <header>{this.props.title}</header>
            <p>{this.props.description}</p>
            <span className="opt_serv_price">{this.props.price}</span>
            <osDD/>
        </div>
    )
}
});
```

But still it didn't work. As a looked at more examples in the official docs (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html) I noticed  that all of them define their ReactClass with variables capitalized.

So I had to change, my classname from `osDD` to `OsDD` and it worked! I think I missed somewhere in the docs about this. Would appreciate it if someone could point me to where it's stated.

Comment: _React's JSX uses the upper vs. lower case convention to distinguish between local component classes and HTML tags_. [Link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components).

Answer (score 1):

Great job on finding the answer, JSX will run createElement behind the scenes for you. Since you can technically come up with any random DOM element in html you tell JSX you want to render a React class and not a plane old DOM element by capitalizing the first letter.

Here's the doc: [React Class Capitalization](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

> **HTML Tags vs. React Components**
> React can either render HTML tags (strings) or React components (classes).
>
> To render an HTML tag, just use lower-case tag names in JSX
>
> To render a React Component, just create a local variable that starts with an upper-case letter